# gnu parallel with matlab parfor loop

Tags: bash, matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am running a matlab function through a bash script  using gnu parallel. The matlab function takes as input a single file which I am passing in using the find command in bash:

```
find $path -name *.nc | parallel - j 8 "echo{} | matlab -nojvm -nosplash -r matlab_function"
```

The matlab function uses a parfor loop and I am having trouble determining if this is really even working or not because it seems like it is going slower than if I simply run the function manually in the matlab gui. I mean it is definitely executing, but I am concerned that because the bash script is opening 8 instances of matlab, each of them running a parfor loop, that maybe they are not actually able to run parfors? Can anyone help me at least determine whether or not this is actually running correctly in parallel?

Oh and I currently have two terminal instances open running the script on different portions of data so really I believe there are 16 matlab instances running.

Thank you

Comment: What does `ps` say? What does `uptime` say your load is? What does `top` say about your CPU/etc. usage (hit `1` in top to get per-cpu lines at the top)?

Answer (score 0):

You do not write how many CPU cores you have. If you only have 8, then you will not be able to tell the difference. So try running fewer jobs in parallel and see in `top` if the processes use > 100%.

Comment: what does it mean if they are running > 100% ? I did see that there are 16 matlabs open and some of them are in the 90% range some more like 50% and occasionally some go above 100 and I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: @djikay what does it mean if they are running > 100% ? I did see that there are 16 matlabs open and some of them are in the 90% range some more like 50% and occasionally some go above 100 and I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Please do not keep it secret how many CPUs you have. If you want help we _REALLY_ need that information.